# Best way to backup data on android when connection to server is lost

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android application where it will be communicating with a server all the item. Specifically, the android interface has many fields were the user fills in the data and send them to the server (Glassfish with Oracle Backend). My concern is: what is the best way to store data when the connection is lost so that when it connects again, I can send the data to the server.

Note 1: Data are all textual and it can reach 1.5 MB in size. Also, there is a plan to save images too.

Note 2: I know about SQLite, but is this the best solution or there is sth else?

Finally, I would like to thank all of you for your collaboration

Answer (score 4):

**SQLite** is a good solution.

Because your data size can be reach upto 1.5 MB you must store your data in an easy way, which you can easily retrive the stored data when tha connection is available to the server.

I also have used SQLite in android and i believe it will be the best resolution for your problem.

For more comparison see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

Use SQLite to save your data offline, clear the table if data is sent to server. Best method.

Use SharedPreference to save keys(sent Succesfully) and values(true/false).
 - Ex `Save Data in DB >> Send data to Server >> Get Acknowledgement (if failed, resend till success) >> Update keys >> delete data in DB >> Repeat cycle`

Use Cache/local directories to save **images**

Answer (score 1):

You can use an SQLite database, and have your rows include a Synced tag. If the sync fails, add a row to the database with Synced = False. When you later Sync the data and get a successful return message, you can update the row in the database to Synced = True (if you plan to have offline cached data) or simply remove the row if you're using the table as a temporary store.

You do not want to use SharedPreferences in this instance.

If you're going to use the database to keep a persistent store synced with the server online, you may wish to also look at the following:

- [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/)
- [GreenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/)